# Configure a File Type Item through GPO for a Win2008 R2 Terminal server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I try to configure a file-type item for .axd filetype.

There I have troubles with the associated class for this file-type.

E.g. I have tried it with "XML-document" (xml-informations are included at the files with .axd) but it does not work.
The .axd file will not be opened with the associated application.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Best regards

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the problem you are having with opening .axd files, but maybe you should try with a different Program (e.g. Notepad++)

Filetypes are stored in the Registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes).
You should be able to edit the Registry via GPs under Computer OR User Configuration\Preferences\Windows Settings\Registry